# Is this the right way to fetch an image from a URL in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, urllib

I need to retrieve a URL in Python and get it as a Pillow image.

```py
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import urllib.request

url = input('Enter an image URL:\n> ')
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
imdata = r.read()
imdata_wrapper = BytesIO(imdata)
im = Image.open(imdata_wrapper)

im.show()
```

This seems like a rather roundabout way to do this (fetch the image, read out its data into a blob, convert said blob into a `BytesIO` object, then, finally, open such as an image).

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can't you skip the `read` and `BytesIO` calls? The return value from `urllib.request.urlopen` should be the kind of file-like object that `Image.open` wants.

Comment: @Blckknght I suspected something like that, but I can't find how to do it. `urllib.request.urlopen()` returns an "`http.client.HTTPResponse` object" which doesn't seem to be able to be used for much.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: What error do you get when you try to pass the `HTTPResponse` object directly to `Image.open`?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude - `Image.open` needs a file object which supports `read`, `seek` and `tell`, the later two of which  `http.client.HTTPResponse` doesn't support, so storing it in a BytesIO seams the right thing to do.

Comment: @mata Thanks! So this system with the read() and BytesIO is, in fact, the only way for now?

Comment: Yes, it's probably the best way.

Comment: The [docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes) state: `If you have an entire image in a string, wrap it in a BytesIO object, and use open() to load it.` So your solution seems to be the intended one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments -- Nope; that's what the docs even suggest!

> If you have an entire image in a bytestring, wrap it in a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object, and use [`PIL.Image.open()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) to load it.

---

Though, as of Python 3.5, even that's unnecessary since [`HTTPResponse`s are already buffered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects) (this applies to [other URL libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54243274/1874170), too, such as `requests` and `urllib3`):

```py
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request

url = input('Enter an image URL:\n> ')

r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
im = Image.open(r)

im.show()
```