# How to download an image straight to a bytesIO variable?

Tags: python, image, url, download

I have an existing `url` of an image, 
I want to download the image straight to a variable (no need to actually download it, maybe get it from a response?

The end result will be "download an image into a `BytesIO()` variable".

What is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You can use requests:

```
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get(url)
image_data = BytesIO(response.content)
```

Note this works in Python 3.X

Answer (score 1):

You could also just duck-type the underlying urllib3 response object, which is for many practical purposes the same interface as a BytesIO anyway.

Example using the PNG of your identicon:

```
>>> url = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/33f6d36c91913f4b6776525a09d131d0?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"
>>> resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
>>> resp.raw
<urllib3.response.HTTPResponse at 0x7fffe88927b8>
>>> resp.raw.read()
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x08\x06\x00\x00\x00szz\xf4\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0e\xc4\x00\x00\x0e\xc4\x01\x95+\x0e\x1b\x00\x00\x00\xf6IDATX\x85\xedW1\x12\xc20\x0c\x93\xb9\x0em\xc3\xeb\x98)3?b\x87\x9d\xcf\xd1\xa4[\xcd\x06\xd89bz\xe50C\xb4\xe5\xda\xaa\xba\xc8Qlbf\xc6\x0b\xd2.\xa1\x84\xfe\xda\x17\x9f\xa7!\x01\xf1\xfd\xf3\xee\xdc\x81\xb6\xf4Xo\x8al?@\x15\xd0h\xcf\xdbS\x0b\nO\x8f^\xfd\x02\x80\xe98\x81\xa3(\x1b\x81\xfe"k\x84G\xf9\xeet\x98\xa4\x00M@\x81\xb2\x9f\n\xc2\xc8\xc5"\xcb\xf8\n\\\xc0\x1fX\xe0. \xb7\xc0\xd82\xed\xf1b\x04\x08\x0b\xddw\xa0\n }\x17\xe8s\xbe\xd6\xf34\xc8\x9c\xd1|Y\x11.=\xe7&\x0c.w\x0b\xaa\x80*\xc0]\x00\xc5\xbd\xbc\xdcWg\xbd\x01\x9d3\xcdW\xcf\xfc\x07\xd09\xe3n\x81\xbb\x80<\x8aG.\xf6\x04V\xdfo\xcd\r\xfa[\xf7\x1d\xa8\x02h\xbe\xcd\xb2\x1fP};\x82\\Z9\x91\xcd\r\xcas=w4V\x13\xba4\'\xac~B\xcf\x1d\xee\x16\xb8\x0b\xb8\x03\x91\x99Z?\x1eYA8\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```